# WARNING: Encoded password does not look like BCrypt

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-oauth2

Controller class method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String adminPage() {
    return "privatePage";
```

spring-security configuration:

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
</http>
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder ref="bCryptPasswordEncoder" />
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="passwordEncoder.encode(123456)"
                authorities="hasRole(ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER)" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
<beans:bean  id="bCryptPasswordEncoder"     class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="10" />
</beans:bean>
```

Error:

> Your login attempt was not successful, try again.

Reason: Bad credentials.

Appreciate any response.

Comment: I very much doubt that you can specify Java code as a value to "password": `password="passwordEncoder.encode(123456)"`. I've never seen it before. Try `password="$2a$10$dFJH9bHHz28xp0pF4dvVx./5EEPGYjdrAkJp8yzaC49aYOHT4FaIe"` instead.

Comment: password="passwordEncoder.encode(123456)", This is because while giving password="123456".  "Encoded password does not look like BCrypt", WARNING message was coming, so i was trying to do password encode through PasswordEncode method.But for this also not able to login.

Comment: password="$2a$10$dFJH9bHHz28xp0pF4dvVx./5EEPGYjdrAkJp8yzaC49aYOHT4FaIe". Doing this also same problem. This is like  generating encoded password equivalent to 123456.

Comment: I am using Spring 5.0.0.RELEASE. If i'll go same application through Annotation based it's working fine.

Comment: `passwordEncoder.encode(123456)` is Java code. It will work with Java configuration. But it hardly works in XML, a non-Java environment. And can you be more specific about "also same problem": Can't you log in, do you get the *Encoded password does no look like BCrypt" error, or both?

Comment: k,"Encoded password does no look like BCrypt" this Error i am getting after giving password="$2a$10$dFJH9bHHz28xp0pF4dvVx./5EEPGYjdrAkJp8yzaC49aYOHT4FaIe".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

```
<user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="$2a$10$hbxecwitQQ.dDT4JOFzQAulNySFwEpaFLw38jda6Td.Y/cOiRzDFu"
                authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </user-service>
```

### Comment

admin@123 equivalent to $2a$10$hbxecwitQQ.dDT4JOFzQAulNySFwEpaFLw38jda6Td.Y/cOiRzDFu this encoded password.
So, In password text give admin@123.

### class for converting Encode Value

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder b=new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
String str=b.encode("admin@123");
System.out.println("Encoding "+str);
```

Generating Encoded values.